# Simple name server alternative a la /etc/hosts

Tags: hostname, hosts

I use `/etc/hosts` to define names to local addresses in the network, so I can type `ssh user@raspberry` instead of `ssh user@192.168.0.5`.

It works very well for a single machine, but now I need to replicate to many machines. So naturally, a central name server in the server is a better approach, so I configure the machine once and the changes are all made in the server.

The question is: Whats the better way to implement this? I want to to keep it simple, just like using the `hosts` file, and something like BIND **seems** to be a little overwhelming. And what the pros and cons of a certain approach?

Comment: Install [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/), bind it to the local interface on your server, and configure all machines to use it.  It's a good DNS cache, and it can also act as an authoritative server for your local network.  Nor particularly simple, but still a whole lot simpler than `bind`.

Comment: Why not install a web panel?  Those usually have a very simple DNS configuration interface.

Answer (score 6):

Dnsmasq will serve up the data in your /etc/hosts file as a dns server - authoritative for your lical domain and providing caching for internet lookups. It also provides a dhcp server.

Answer (score 2):

For `ssh(1)` you would create `~/.ssh/config`

```
host raspberry
  hostname 192.168.0.5
  user user
```

Then you can just do `ssh raspberry`

Of course, DNS is the solution for central host database, that is exactly it's function! You don't have to use bind if that sounds too frightening, there are smaller servers like [dnsmasq](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2013/07/18/how-to-dns-spoofing-with-a-simple-dns-server-using-dnsmasq/) which could do it more easily.